# Can a peer dependency be imported as an external via the global object

Tags: typescript, webpack, micro-frontend

I am building a typescript app using a micro-frontend architecture w/ react, webpack and ts-loader. We have three key players the Host, the MFE, and an internal component package.

My issue is all three use styled-components and I'm trying to utilize the one instance of it across the three pieces of code.

The host installs styled-components as a dependency, and passes it through to the MFE via global. This much works.

However when the MFE calls the component library, the component library tries to access the styled-components instance and fails.

The component library imports styled-components as a peer dependency. My understanding is that it should resolve styled-components the same way the MFE did since it's running inside of the MFE. However it just gets an undefined error, every time the code hits a reference to the styled-components library.

Is my thinking right in that the component library should be able to see the peer dependency that is imported via external or no?

*I have tried installing the component library on the host and passing it to the MFE as on the global object and this works since the styled-component dependency is installed as a dependency on the host so it has no issue finding it.

However I would like a solution that wouldn't require me to export the component library via the host.*

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.